# SelectDirectory() doesnt work. It always returns false

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Whenever I call `Res := SelectDirectory('Test', '', Dir)`, `Res` is always false. I expect a window to open on the phone where I can choose a folder. The second parameter being blank should mean all folders are shown.

I tried some folders that I know exist, like the Programs folder, SharedCamera, etc. No difference, it still does not work.

```pascal
Root:= '';
Res:= SelectDirectory('Test', Root, Dir); // Always returns false.

{I tried Root:= System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPicturesPath + System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar;
and Root:= System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPicturesPath + System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + '*.*';
and several others.}
```

I always get `Res = False` and no window is shown.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Which platform(s) are you targeting? Last time I checked, `SelectDirectory()` was only implemented for Windows and OSX, since those platforms provide native OS APIs for displaying a folder selection dialog. Mobile platforms do not, and Embarcadero did not implement custom dialogs for them. I don't know if things have changed since I last checked.

Comment: If you try the code in the answer I've just posted, you need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Get into the habit of writing tests into your code.

Comment: Which specific version of Delphi are you using? Firemonkey has changed considerably between versions, especially with the mobile device support.

Comment: It was on Android and I am running Seattle. And I am running it on a phone (An LG). Sorry. 
I could not find any description of where SelectDirectoty() is supported, but I assumed it was running unde Android since it did. When I tried to do a single step through the code into where it as defined, everything was apparently working, until the binary was actually called. This is where I was expecting to see something on the display, but instead it immidiately returned with result = false and Dir = ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made my own version instead of the official one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works fine for me, compiled into an FMX project in Delphi Seattle.

Try single-stepping it in the debugger, and see it working.  What happens when the `Asset` line executes?

```
procedure TForm2.TestSelectDirectory;
var
  BoolRes : Boolean;
  Dir : String;
  Path : String;
  S : String;
begin
  Path := 'C:\Temp';
  Assert(DirectoryExists(Path));
  BoolRes := SelectDirectory('Testing SelectDirectory', Path, Dir);
  if BoolRes then
    S := 'Succeeded '
  else
    S := 'Failed  ';
  S := Format(S + '%s', [Dir]);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;
```

Comment: Is this running on a phone? Which OS? The OP didn't mention an OS, but does say *I expect a window to open on the phone where I can choose a folder.*

Comment: Thanks, @KenWhite.  Win10 - I confess I missed the reference to the OP's phone.  I'll take this down if it's not even of marginal help.

Comment: Yeah, the poster didn't do a very good job of identifying the actual problem. No Delphi version, no platform target. Makes it difficult. :-)

Comment: I tried doing a single step of the code above by MartynY, like this:

  Path:= TPath.GetSharedPicturesPath;

I tried different paths. The code passed through the assert, but returned false in all cases.Next I will try it on another phone.

Comment: I tried it on two different phones, but no difference.